# How to optimize where clause of SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

Table **Employee**

```
ID Name DOJ
------------------
1   A   2018-12-12
2   B   2018-11-12
......
```

Query:

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM Employee 
WHERE YEAR(DOJ) = 2018
```

Having huge amounts of data in the `employee` table, how to optimize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid function in `where` clause as

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM Employee e
WHERE DOJ >= '20180101' and DOJ <= '20181231';
```

So, that query would be called as *SARGable* that can take advantage of index if already exists

For your current query use of any function in `where` clause that will make a query *non-sargable*. So, *SQL* optimizer can't use an index on `DOJ`, even if one exists.

Tiny word of advice always use ANSI *SQL* Date format `YYYYMMDD`

Answer (score 2):

Don't apply any function directly on table column `DOJ`. Instead use this -

```
SELECT NAME FROM Employee WHERE DOJ >= '2018-01-01' AND DOJ <= '2018-12-31'
```

Also, make sure there is an `Index` on column `DOJ`.
Check out this -
[Sargable Query](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the query, you can create `INDEX` on `DOJ` field:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_doj ON Employee (DOJ);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an index to DOJ column or partition the table on year as you are saying its a huge table